# How to understand primary workers while autoscaling GCP Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I was going thru the documentation of [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#gcloud-command_1) a dataproc cluster.
The doc says autoscaling needs a yaml file before you create a cluster with minimum configuration as given below:

```
workerConfig:
  minInstances: 2
  maxInstances: 100
  weight: 1
secondaryWorkerConfig:
  minInstances: 0
  maxInstances: 100
  weight: 1
basicAlgorithm:
  cooldownPeriod: 2m
  yarnConfig:
    scaleUpFactor: 0.05
    scaleDownFactor: 1.0
    scaleUpMinWorkerFraction: 0.0
    scaleDownMinWorkerFraction: 0.0
    gracefulDecommissionTimeout: 1h
```

Down the line in the same documentation, I saw this:

> Avoid scaling primary workers: Primary workers run HDFS Datanodes,
> while secondary workers are compute-only workers. Avoid scaling
> primary workers to avoid running into these issues. For example:

```
     workerConfig:
       minInstances: 10
       maxInstances: 10
     secondaryWorkerConfig:
       minInstances: 0
       maxInstances: 100
```

I created a cluster on dataproc that has the following vm instances:

```
name               role
dev-spark-m      master
dev-spark-w-0    worker
dev-spark-w-1    worker
```

When the documentation says, `Avoid scaling primary workers`, should I understand that the configuration of key `workerConfig` in yaml file corresponds to autoscaling the master `dev-spark-m` and I should avoid doing it ?
In that case, can I simply keep the configuration of `secondaryWorkerConfig` with no configuration for `workerConfig` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no scaling the master. The `workerConfig` field is always about the primary workers.
2. Setting the `minInstances` and `maxInstances` fields to the same value is equivalent to "no scaling".
3. You will have to always specify at least the `workerConfig.maxInstances` value, and the `workerConfig.minInstances` value defaults to 2.